# What does a function followed by a colon and a semicolon do?

Tags: javascript, function, sharepoint

I'm digging through SharePoint 2010's hellish JavaScript code (God have mercy on my soul), and one of the many bizarre lines I'm running into is this one, repeated frequently:

```
ULSrLq:;
```

`ULSrLq` is the following function (beautified for readability):

```
function ULSrLq() {
    var o = new Object;
    o.ULSTeamName = "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation";
    o.ULSFileName = "core.js";
    return o;
}
```

As far as I can tell, this does absolutely nothing. `ULSrLq` is never called, and removing the line in question seems to have no impact on the page's functioning. The following snippet contains a function `foo` that shows an alert and a line similar to the SharePoint mystery (`foo:;`). Running it does nothing.

```js
function foo() {
    alert("foo called");
}

foo:;
```

I'm not even sure why this is syntactically valid. Can anybody offer any insight as to the purpose of this structure?

Comment: Looks like a [label](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.12). And yes it is *completely* pointless.

Comment: @Pointy Is there any reason why the label would share its name with a function?

Comment: No particular reason. Because of how JavaScript labels work, a labeled null statement (just a semicolon) is completely useless, because the only way you can *use* a label is from inside the statement. There's nothing inside a null statement :)